# In which code page is the euro sign at index 172 (0xAC)?

Tags: .net, windows, firefox, codepages

I entered the user name "süp€r" in a Firefox (50.0.2) Basic auth dialog which results in the transfered header `Authorization: Basic c/xwrHI6`.

None of the 140 encodings provided by .NET 4.6.2 is able to decode the bytes `73 FC 70 AC 72 3A` into the original string:

```
var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String("c/xwrHI6").Dump();
var query=
    from ei in Encoding.GetEncodings()
    let e = ei.GetEncoding()
    let s = e.GetString(bytes)
    where s.Contains('€')
    select new { e.CodePage, e.EncodingName, e.WebName, s };
new { bytes, R = query.ToList()}.Dump();
```

Comment: It's clearly a broken system. € in Unicode is 20AC and only the lower byte is taken into account it seems. Care to test with other characters?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen the 'ü'/252/0xFC (already part of the test) is valid in 14 encodings: windows-125X, most of iso-8859-X and utf-7 , NOT utf-8

Comment: If I use the uri `http://süp€r:@localhost/...` in the very same browser tab the base64 encoded token becomes `"c8O8cOKCrHI6"` representing the text as valid utf-8 bytes: `73 C3 BC 70 E2 82 AC 72 3A`